# Can't ping 8.8.8.8 from router, but can ping it from LAN?

Tags: freebsd, routing, pfsense, nslookup

I have `pfSense` router with 2 WANs.

I noticed, that if one WAN is down, then I can't ping `8.8.8.8` from router. Simultaneously, I am able to ping this address from within LAN, i.e. it can pass through router.

How is this possible?

I checked pinger (by Web interfcate) and found, that it doesn't use this address to check gateway alive. Previously I was using it but now de-configured.

What else can still bind `8.8.8.8` to one of WANs and hot to catch it?

**UPDATE**

My suscpicion is that only one WAN available from the router itsellf, because one of them is marked "default". When default WAN is down, then no internet is available for router at all.

Simultaneously, they have special "multi tier" thing to load balance two WANs, which makes that router still serves internet for LAN machines.

Is this possible?

Comment: Shot in the dark, but from your router, have you tried ping with the `-I <interface>` option to configure the source IP address of the ping? If by default, the ping from the router uses the source IP address of the WAN link that is down, then it will fail.  Force it to use the interface that is up.

Comment: The goal is to get normal failover. It has no sense if DNS is available only via "default" interface.